# How to compare 2 ARIMA model predictions using mean squared prediction error

Tags: time-series, probability, mathematical-statistics

How can I compare the predictions of 2 arima models using mean square prediction error in R, given that I know what the observed values are. Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your data, your models, & your goals here? Are these models of the same data? Etc.

Comment: Given one set of data. Had to select a suitable model. Selected two ARIMA models, but now want to compare the forecasts made by two of these using this technique, after I have been given the next 10 observed values

Answer (score 1):

Load all the data into one time series, then split the data into training and test sets, per "The Forecaster's Toolbox" chapter in [Hyndman and Athana­sopou­los](http://Split%20the%20data%20into%20training%20and%20test%20sets,%20per%20%22The%20Forecaster's%20Toolbox%22%20chapter%20in%20Hyndman%20and%20Athana%C2%ADsopou%C2%ADlos). The test set will contain your 10 new data points.  The training set will contain your original data.

Run arima model on the training set (Tr). Forecast (saved here in aaf). Then use accuracy() to get the accuracy of these forecasts relative to the test data (Te)

```
aa <- auto.arima(Tr)  #I used auto.arima here, but you have a specific model already
aa  
aaf <- forecast(aa,h=10) 
accuracy(aaf,Te)
# repeat for the second forecast
```

Repeat for your other model. Compare.